# how to get list of unique chars from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, duplicates

I have some text files, each with a mix of western and chinese characters. I want a list of the chinese characters that appear in each file.

I have tried

```
ch = text.match(/[\u4E00-\u9FFF]/g); // unicode usual chinese characters - that'll do for me
if (ch != null) {
    alert(ch);
}
```

This gives me the list of chinese characters, but with some repetitions. For example:

```
肉,捕,兵,死,兵,半,水
```

for a file

```
卵,水,半,水,土,木,水,清,慢,底,海,海,海,清,清,清,木,清,慢,底,清,土,半,水,水,土,半,水,土
```

for another...

1) I don't need those commas. Where did they come from? (I can take them off with a single replace, but since I'm using regex, I think it may be faster if I solve it inside the regex itself.)

2) How to get only unique values? For example:

```
肉捕兵死半水
```

for the first file

```
卵水半土木清慢底海
```

for the second...

Comment: `I think it may be faster if I solve it inside the regex itself` The marginal and unnoticeable speed boost you *might* get by putting it into the regex is not worth the mental hassle of having a more complicated regex. Split your regex up if possible. They're difficult enough to understand at a glance, so anything to make them more readable is usually worth it.

Comment: From the other side, the mental hassle I had for constructing a more complicated regex only happened once. The speed boost i might get (it's important to test this) would happen so many times that I tend to disagree with you, and agree with the philosophy of design of this gentleman: www.micosyen.com :)

Comment: From his site: "My design philosophy, consistently and concisely applied for a quarter century, is that there is no greater elegance than simplicity. 8 bits are preferred over 16 and 16 over 32. 5 MHz clocks are preferred over 50, and 50 over 500. Assembly is preferred over C, and C over C++. The elimination of software bloat is the key to eliminating hardware bloat. The elimination of hardware bloat is the key to creating a product that rises above the cacophony of mediocrity to garner praise for innovation, performance and cost-effectiveness."

Comment: And don't forget to check his 44kB Windoze mp3 player! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commas come from default array to string conversion. use `ch.join('')` to convert array to string instead.

To remove duplicate values, use this line:

```
ch = text.match(/([\u4E00-\u9FFF])/g);
ch = ch.filter(function (c, i) { return ch.indexOf(c) === i; }).join('');
```

Comment: love it! you forget to return value. `join()` will not affect `ch`

Comment: Thank you! It works! But at least in Mozilla it needs to be ch = ch.filter, because "filter does not mutate the array on which it is called" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}


ch = text.match(/([\u4E00-\u9FFF])/g);
var result_string = ch.getUnique().join("");
```

Comment: Defining an entire helper function for a very specific use case is overkill, especially when it's being used to extend native JavaScript objects.

Comment: I have thought such a trivial task (unique() in R) would be implemented inside regex, but it seems not.

Comment: No. A regex is designed to match and/or substitute patterns. It's not a regular expressions job to sort or filter the results it finds; such things are the responsibility of interfaces like Array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text    =   "卵水半水土木水清慢底海海海清清清木清慢底清土半水水土半水土",


    re      =   /([\u4E00-\u9FFF])/g,
    unique  =   {},
    chars   =   "", c;

while(c = re.exec(text)){
    if(!unique[c[0]]){
        chars += c[0];
        unique[c[0]] = true;
    }
}
chars.split("");
```

Which returned:

```
["卵", "水", "半", "土", "木", "清", "慢", "底", "海"]
```

And yes, the commas you're seeing are when a browser typecasts an array to a string: it joins the the string representations of each value together with commas. I'm guessing that came from the call to "alert" in your original example, which was being supplied an array (returned from the string's "Match" method).

Array's "filter" method isn't supported in legacy browsers, but it's quite easy to polyfill (and certainly not necessary to if you're only concerned with supporting agents as recent as IE9).

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-liner solution with regex:

```
input.match(/([\u4E00-\u9FFF])(?![\s\S]*\1)/g)
```

However, **I wouldn't recommend using it**, since it will have O(n * k) complexity in worst case (when the string contains mostly Chinese characters), where n is the length of the string and k is the number of unique Chinese characters. Why O(n * k)? Since the look-ahead `(?![\s\S]*\1)` basically says "assert that you can't find another instance of whatever matched in first capturing group in the rest of the string".

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977826/1400768) by @Ruben Kazumov is a reasonable alternative. Its complexity depends on the implementation of setting and getting property in an Object, which should be sub-linear per operation in a reasonable implementation.